# Is there a replacement for the Sylvania FB40CW/RS/SS-6 34W Super Saver bulb?

Tags: kitchens, light, bulb

Our Kitchen Light bulb finally went out.  I need 2 Sylvania super saver FB40CW/RS/SS-6 34W bulbs to replace it.  It seems they are not available.  Has the number changed? Is their a new replacement bulb?

Comment: I had no problem finding them using Google. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that Sylvania no longer manufactures the FB40CW/RS/SS. The only FB40CW bulb they manufacture now is the [**FB40CWX**](https://ecom.sylvania.com/sylvaniab2b/b2b/start.do?browsername=mozilla%2F5.0%2520%2528windows%2520nt%25206.1%253B%2520rv%253A65.0%2529%2520gecko%2F20100101%2520firefox%2F65.0&browsermajor=5&browserminor=5) which is a 40 watt bulb.

There are a handful of suppliers that still have the FB40CW/RS/SS (or a compatible) but I have yet to locate one that sells a quantity of less than 12. I would consider replacing that fixture with a modern LED fixture.